# pass JSON Objects and Arrays as parameters into the Angular 2 http calls

Tags: typescript, angular5

I want to pass the below JSON object and Array to the parameter of HTTP request into my Angular 5 project.

param1:

```
{"param_1":"abc","param_2":"xyz","param_3":"123"}
```

param2:

```
[{"f_key_1":"id1","f_key_2":"12","f_key_3":"xyz1"},{"f_key_1":"id2","f_key_2":"13","f_key_3":"xyz2"}]
```

By using the following code to create the string from object and array

```
public updateParam(dataParam: any) {
    let params = new URLSearchParams();
    for (let field in dataParam) {
        if (typeof (dataParam[field]) == 'object' || dataParam[field] instanceof Array) {
            params.set(field, JSON.stringify(dataParam[field]));
        } else {
            params.set(field, dataParam[field]);
        }
    }

    return this.http.patch('param/update', params.toString())
        .map((res: Response) => res.json())
        .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
}
```

I thought this is the proper way of doing it, but it is not working. The reason is, it passes [object Object] for the param1 and [[object Object],[object Object]] for param2 value.
I can resolve it by creating the string in a JSON like structure and pass it as the parameter. But that is not a standard way to do this.

Is there any standard way to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Change the `if-else` part like below. Add `JSON.stringify` to all variable:

```
if (typeof (dataParam[field]) == 'object' || dataParam[field] instanceof Array) {
    params.set(JSON.stringify(field), JSON.stringify(dataParam[field]));
} else {
    params.set(JSON.stringify(field), JSON.stringify(dataParam[field]));
}
```